# How to crete a new XML from an existing XML nodes in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have to extract a node occurring multiple times in XML file at node level 3 to a new xml file.

XML looks like

```
<Start>
    <first>  
        <Second>
            <Third>
            </Third>
            <Third>
            </Third>
            <Third>
            </Third> 
        </Second>
    </first> 
</Start>
```

and what i need is something like this

```
<Start> 
    <first>  
        <Second>
            <Third>
            </Third>  
        </Second>
    </first>
</Start>
```

I need a Java code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the DOM library, it's easy.

- Load the original xml into a Dom object.
- Look for those nodes with a Tag like "Third"
- Keep the first one, remove if others.
- Save the XML

Comment: Yes, tell me where are you getting stucked and I will try to help you. But try the code by yourself